# upload a pre-trained model locally into databricks

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, mlflow

Is it possible to upload a pre-trained machine learning model that was trained on a different environment on databricks, and serve it? Or is it impossible on Databricks ?

Comment: what kind of ML model? Scikit learn, or something else?

Comment: well, it's a pre-trained model that i saved as model.pkl, it's on tensorflow

Comment: it's seems for me that I have to train the model again on databricks in order to have an experiment, and then serve the model, but I wanted to just use the pre-trained model that was saved on model.pkl form my local computer, and serve it directly on databricks

Comment: You can directly log your model into Databricks model registry from your local machine using the mlflow.log_model: https://docs.databricks.com/applications/mlflow/access-hosted-tracking-server.html

Comment: but could it be possible to register the model without any training in databricks ? I wish I could re-use the model.pkl directly on databricks environment

Comment: you should be able to use specific log_model implementation. For Tensorflow: https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tensorflow.html#mlflow.tensorflow.log_model

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use a trained model on another environment is to use MLflow. You can save several models with different versions and load them in any Databricks environment. I advise you to consult the following documentation [here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html).